# Angular.js loading without reference?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I'm working on reverse engineering a User Interface that is functioning minus a few bugs. It was coded in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript and pulls data via a REST API. The UI is set up in a Windows environment.

When I was looking through the index.html home page for the UI, there is quite a bit of Angular.js used in the interface, yet the script that calls angular.js is commented out. I'm confused about how angular.js could run on the server without being called. Is there some way to reference or parse angular.js on a server without referencing it in the HTML without calling it like you normally would?

I'm confused. Any ideas would be helpful. I included the index.html file below:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store"/>
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1"/>
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="content/images/favicon.png"/>
    <!--<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script src="/js/app.js"></script>-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/icomoon/style.css?0.0.0.164">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/css/bootstrap.css?0.0.0.164">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="bower_components/bootstrap-dialog/dist/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css?0.0.0.164">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/base/jquery-ui.css?0.0.0.164">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.css?0.0.0.164">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/spectrum/spectrum.css?0.0.0.164">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="custom_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css?0.0.0.164">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css?0.0.0.164">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css?0.0.0.164">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom_components/loader-display/loadDisplay.css?0.0.0.164">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/css/keyboard.css?0.0.0.164">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/css/noty.css?0.0.0.164">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom_components/ladda-bootstrap/ladda-themeless.css?0.0.0.164">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/css/daikin_mis_hmi.css?0.0.0.164">
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <!-- if logged in-->
            <button ng-if="!isHideMainControls" type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">ToggleNav</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" ng-click="goHome()">
                <img src="content/images/logo.png">
            </a>
            <span ng-if="!isHideMainControls" class="visible-xs visible-sm" alarm-indicator></span>
            <span ng-if="!isHideMainControls" class="visible-sm" dm-keyboard-widget></span>
            <span ng-if="!isHideMainControls" class="visible-xs visible-sm" network-mode></span>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"><span
                        ng-if="!isHideMainControls" network-mode></span></li>
                <li class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                    <span ng-if="!isHideMainControls" alarm-indicator></span>

                    <div dm-keyboard-widget></div>
                </li>
                <!-- if logged in-->
                <li class="divider-vertical hidden-xs hidden-sm"></li>
                <li ng-class="{'display-none': !isApplicationLoaded}" class="display-none">
                    <div ng-cloak class="logged-in-user-info" data-toggle="">
                        <div class="user-name">
                            {{sessionUser.firstName}} {{sessionUser.lastName}}
                        </div>
                        <div ng-if="!isHideMainControls" ng-hide="sessionUser.isGuest" class="log-out">
                            <a ng-click="logout();" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>{{generalLabels.genlogout}}</a>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-show="sessionUser.isGuest" class="log-out">
                            <a ui-sref="login" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>{{generalLabels.genlogin}}</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="visible-xs visible-sm dropdown">
                    <ul class="submenu" ng-include src="'views/shared-templates/main-menu-items.html'">
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="main-wrapper">
    <dm-main-menu class="hidden-block-xs hidden-block-sm"></dm-main-menu>
    <div style="display: none" id="appFailedLoadMessage"></div>
    <div class="wrap-loader" ng-hide="isApplicationLoaded">
        <div id="load-background" class="show-background">
            <div class="loading-display">
                <img class="ajax-loader" src="custom_components/loader-display/img/ajax-loader.gif">
                <br>

                <div class="display-none">
                    <img src="content/images/noty/ErrorMessageBackground.png" width="1" height="1" alt=""/>
                    <img src="content/images/noty/SuccessBackground.png" width="1" height="1" alt=""/>
                    <img src="content/images/noty/accept.png" width="1" height="1" alt=""/>
                    <img src="content/images/noty/error_ico.png" width="1" height="1" alt=""/>
                    <img src="content/images/noty/wrong.png" width="1" height="1" alt=""/>

                    <img src="content/images/control-buttons/on_off1.png" width="1" height="1" alt=""/>
                    <img src="content/images/control-buttons/on_off2.png" width="1" height="1" alt=""/>
                    <img src="content/images/control-buttons/switcher1.png" width="1" height="1" alt=""/>
                    <img src="content/images/control-buttons/switcher2.png" width="1" height="1" alt=""/>
                </div>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- BreadCrumbs go here-->
    <div ng-if="!isHideMainControls" class="breadcrumbs">
        <div class="container">
            <div ncy-breadcrumb></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div ui-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#" class="go-top"><i class="icon-arrow-up icon-large"></i> {{generalLabels.gentop}}</a>

<div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 hidden-xs visible-sm visible-md visible-lg text-center-xxs text-center-xs text-left-sm text-left-md text-left-lg">
                <!-- Easter Egg - footer double click show current viewport size and version -->
                <span class="js-ui-version" style="display:none"></span>
                <span class="js-viewport-size" style="display:none"></span>
            </div>
            <div ng-class="{'display-none': !isApplicationLoaded}"
                 class="display-none col-sm-4 hidden-xs visible-sm visible-md visible-lg text-center-sm text-center-md text-center-lg">
                <a target="_blank" ng-href="{{daikinAppliedLink.url}}">{{daikinAppliedLink.text}}</a>
            </div>

            <div ng-class="{'display-none': !isApplicationLoaded}"
                 class="display-none col-sm-4 visible-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg text-center-xxs text-center-xs">
                <a target="_blank" ng-href="{{daikinAppliedLink.url}}">{{daikinAppliedLink.text}}</a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 visible-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg text-center-xxs text-center-xs">
                <!-- Easter Egg - footer double click show current viewport size and version -->
                <span class="js-ui-version" style="display:none"></span>
                <span class="js-viewport-size" style="display:none"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="../bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js?0.0.0.164"></script>
<script src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script>

    if ('addEventListener' in document) {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            FastClick.attach(document.body);
            //todo workaround fixes the problem with selecting a date on the calendar
            FastClick.prototype._needsClick = FastClick.prototype.needsClick;
            FastClick.prototype.needsClick = function (target) {

                if ($(target).parents('.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget').length > 0) {
                    return true;
                }
                return FastClick.prototype._needsClick.call(this, target);
            };
        }, false);
    }

    var scriptsLoadTimeoutSeconds = 60;

    require.config({
        waitSeconds: scriptsLoadTimeoutSeconds,
        baseUrl: './js',
        urlArgs: '0.0.0.164'
    });

    require(["./main"]);

    DisplayAppNotLoadedMessage = function () {
        document.getElementById('load-background').style.display = 'none';

        var errorMessageBlock = document.getElementById('appFailedLoadMessage');

        errorMessageBlock.style.display = 'block';
        errorMessageBlock.innerHTML = 'The system may be either busy or not currently running, please verify status locally at the System Manager PC or try again later.  If the problem persists, refer to IM 1224 for more detailed troubleshooting procedures.';
    };

    // show error message in case of any resources are not loaded
    LoadTimeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
        DisplayAppNotLoadedMessage();
    }, (scriptsLoadTimeoutSeconds + 30) * 1000);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It is technically possible, but unlikely, are you sure there isn't another reference (possibly a different version) somewhere?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. The JS library is located in a subfolder but nothing on the index page that is running Angular.js functionality

Comment: Is the angular codebase included in a minified (built) JS file referenced elsewhere? Many people include the standard angularjs file while developing, and then add it to a build process once development is complete so it is minified.

Comment: This all just becomes a guessing game without code...

Comment: You should provide us some code. I guess showing your `index.html` might be a good start.

Comment: I added the index.html file above for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The index.html file was calling Require.JS, which allows you to asynchronously load your scripts to the home page, but creates some issues in tracking dependencies. It's a JavaScript framework that basically allows you to load up an entire folder of JavaScript files asynchronously.